# Как достать данные из скобок?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

Работаю с БД SQLite. При запросе даются данные, но они в скобках.

Kак мне достать данные из скобок? Ну или, как их убрать, эти скобки?

```py
def listMembers():

    import sqlite3

    Connect = sqlite3.connect("CaptureBotDB.db")
    Cursor = Connect.cursor()

    mess = 'Список пользователей беседы:\n\n'

    for row in Cursor.execute("SELECT first_name, last_name FROM ListMembers"):

        mb = row
        mess += str(mb) + '\n'

    vk.messages.send(
        chat_id=chat_id,
        message=mess,
    )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Пример:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect("CaptureBotDB.db")
cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute("SELECT first_name, last_name FROM ListMembers")

for first, last in cur.fetchall():
     print(f"first_name:\t{first}\tlast_name:\t{last}")
```

---

```
first_name:     Max     last_name:      Mustermann
first_name:     John    last_name:      Doe
first_name:     Иван    last_name:      Иванов
```

---

`cur.fetchall()` возвращает список кортежей. Соответственно можно также обрабатывать его так:

```
for row in cur.fetchall():
     print(f"first_name:\t{row[0]}\tlast_name:\t{row[1]}")
```